# Does TK's text widget support custom text decorators?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm looking for a cross-platform rich text widget that supports non-trivial markup including the following, and I wonder if Tk's text widget can be extended to do them:

- set text background color
- draw lines over and under text
- draw borders around text
- decorate content by overlaying lines and shapes (e.g., filled circles)
- indicate items in a gutter

To give you an idea, look at the middle pane here:

[image]

I read a little about tags, but they seem to be limited to the basics like font, color, etc. I also read about drawing text on the canvas widget, but it looks like standard text editor-like text selection, flow, etc. would be lost.

Thanks very much.

Comment: What would make this relatively easy would be a transparent canvas, a canvas with background='none', that could be placed over a text widget (and scrolled in synchrony).  Another tkinter questioner today really needs a text with transparent background could be placed over a canvas (and not scrolled). Would be a nice tk enhancement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can only do what you've read in the documentation (assuming you've read authoritative documentation).

Specifically, the text widget does not do all that you asked. You **cannot** do the following:

- **draw lines over and under text**. You can use custom fonts with the overstrike and underline attributes turned on but there's no way to add lines over a widget, and you have no control on the visual attributes of the overstrike or underline
- **decorate content by overlaying lines and shapes (e.g., filled circles)**

You can set text background and foreground colors, draw borders around the text, and put items in a gutter. For the latter you would need to use a canvas as the gutter.

Note that if you use a canvas rather than a text widget you can do all of those things (read: the text items of the canvas can be editable), but it would require a large amount of work to implement all of the bindings necessary to use it as an editor. For more information on this approach, see http://effbot.org/zone/editing-canvas-text-items.htm

Comment: Thanks very much, Bryan!